# Do I have the correct logic of the fast api of the application and the implementation of the folder structure in the project

Tags: python

That's about how the logic of my application is implemented. Are there any comments, mistakes or tips?

Here is my folder structure

```
───alembic
├───auth
├───celery
├───crud_routs_func
│   ├───accounts_db_func
│   ├───dash_board_func
├───db
│   ├───backup_folder
├───logger
├───rabbitmq
│   └───mnesia
├───routes
├───utils
```

I will start from the entry point to the applications

main.py

```
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from .db.backup_db import create_backup, create_backup_job
from fastapi import FastAPI
from slowapi import Limiter, _rate_limit_exceeded_handler
from slowapi.util import get_remote_address
from slowapi.errors import RateLimitExceeded
from slowapi.middleware import SlowAPIMiddleware
from .routes.company import CompanyController
from .routes.auth import AuthenticateController
from .routes.account import AccountController
from .routes.links_employee_registration import InviteEmployeeController
from .routes.criteries import CriteriesController
from .routes.dashboard import DashboardController
from .routes.manipulation_employees import ManipulationEmployeesController
from .routes.selling_point import SellingPointsController

import uvicorn
import threading
import schedule

#

limiter = Limiter(key_func=get_remote_address, default_limits=["3/second"])
app = FastAPI()
app.state.limiter = limiter
app.add_exception_handler(RateLimitExceeded, _rate_limit_exceeded_handler)
app.add_middleware(SlowAPIMiddleware)

origins = [
    "http://localhost:8000"
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

create_backup()
schedule.every(1).days.do(create_backup)

def main():
    app.include_router(ManipulationEmployeesController.create_router())
    app.include_router(AccountController.create_router())
    app.include_router(AuthenticateController.create_router())
    app.include_router(CompanyController.create_router())
    app.include_router(SellingPointsController.create_router())
    app.include_router(InviteEmployeeController.create_router())
    app.include_router(CriteriesController.create_router())
    app.include_router(DashboardController.create_router())
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, ws_ping_interval=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=create_backup_job, args=())
    t1.start()
    main()
```

Here is an example of my controller implementation

```
from fastapi_controllers import Controller, get, put
import app.utils.schemas as schemas
from fastapi import Request, HTTPException
from ..auth.access_wrapper import check_access
from app.auth.tokeniser import Tokenisers as _T
from ..crud_routs_func.manipulation_employees_db_func import ManipulationEmployeesDBFunc
import app.utils.resopnse_shemas as resopnse_shemas

class ManipulationEmployeesController(Controller):
    prefix = "/api/manipulation_employees"
    tags = ["manipulation_employees"]

    @get("/get_employees_list")
    @check_access(["owner","director"])
    async def get_employees_list(request:Request, limit:int, role:str, company_id:int=None):
        user = _T.user_items(request)
        user_role = user.get("Role")
        if user_role == role:
            return HTTPException(status_code=403, detail=resopnse_shemas.forbidden_response)
        if user_role == "owner":
            company_id = company_id
        else:
            company_id = ManipulationEmployeesDBFunc.get_company_id_with_employsee_id(user['id'])
        employsee_ids = ManipulationEmployeesDBFunc.employsee_list_workers(company_id, limit, role)
        if employsee_ids == None:
            return HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Problems in the header and most likely not the right role")
        return ManipulationEmployeesDBFunc.get_employsee_data_by_id_list(employsee_ids, role)
    
    @get("/get_employeese")
    @check_access(["owner","director"])
    async def get_employees(request:Request, employsee_id:int):
        return ManipulationEmployeesDBFunc.get_employsee_by_id(employsee_id)

    @put("/update_role")
    @check_access(["owner","director"])
    async def update_employee_role(request:Request, item: schemas.ChangeRole):
        if ManipulationEmployeesDBFunc.change_role(item.employee_id, item.role):
            return {"message":"you have successfully changed your role"}
```

Each of my routes is processed by a wrapper to check access

```
def check_access(roles: List[str]):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        async def wrapper(request: Request, *args, **kwargs):
            access= request.cookies.get("access")
            if access != None:
                user = _T.user_items(request)
                role = user.get("Role")
                if user:
                    email_verification = user.get("email_verification") 
                    tg_verification = user.get("tg_verification")
                    if role == "owner":
                        if not email_verification:
                            raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="For further actions, you need to confirm your email.")
                    if not tg_verification:
                        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="For further actions, you need to authorize your account in telegram bot.")
                    elif role not in roles:
                        raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="You are forbidden to do this.")
                    else:
                        return await func(request, *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="You need to log in to your account.")
            else:
                raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="The token needs to be updated.")
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Also, each of my routes inherits a certain class with access to the database

````
from app.db.connection import DbConnect
import app.utils.models as models
from ..logger.time_date_errors_logger import Logger

class ManipulationEmployeesDBFunc(DbConnect):

    @classmethod
    @Logger.log
    def employsee_list_workers(self, company_id:int, limit:int, role:str):
        if role == "workers":
            query = self.session_work.query(models.Workers.employsee_id).filter(models.Workers.company_id == company_id).limit(limit)
        elif role == "manager":
            query = self.session_work.query(models.Manager.employsee_id).filter(models.Manager.company_id == company_id).limit(limit)
        elif role == "director":
            query = self.session_work.query(models.Director.employsee_id).filter(models.Director.company_id == company_id).limit(limit)
        else:
            return None
        employsee_ids = [result[0] for result in query.all()]
        return employsee_ids

    @classmethod
    @Logger.log
    def get_employsee_data_by_id_list(self, employsee_id_list: list, role) -> list:
        query = self.session_work.query(
            models.Employsee.id, models.Employsee.name, 
            models.Employsee.secondname, models.Employsee.lastname, 
            models.Employsee.phone, models.CredentialsEmploysee.login).join(
            models.CredentialsEmploysee, models.Employsee.id == models.CredentialsEmploysee.employsee_id
            ).filter(models.Employsee.id.in_(employsee_id_list))
        result_list = []
        for row in sorted(query, key=lambda x: x[1]):
            result_dict = {   
                'id': row[0], 'name': row[1], 'secondname': row[2], 
                'lastname': row[3],'phone': row[4], 
                'login': row[5], "role":role}
            result_list.append(result_dict)
        return result_list
    
    @classmethod
    @Logger.log
    def get_employsee_by_id(self, employsee_id:int):
        out_dict = {}
        employsee = self.session_work.query(models.Employsee).filter_by(id = employsee_id).first()
        employsee_cred = self.session_work.query(models.CredentialsEmploysee).filter_by(employsee_id=employsee_id).first()
        out_dict = {}
        out_dict.update({'name': employsee.name})
        out_dict.update({'secondname': employsee.secondname})
        out_dict.update({'lastname': employsee.lastname})
        out_dict.update({'phone': employsee.phone})
        out_dict.update({'login': employsee_cred.login})
        out_dict.update({'tg_id': employsee_cred.tg_id})
        return out_dict
```
````

Comment: nit, typo: It looks like you intended to spell the directory name `crud_routes_func`. Also, I would omit the `_func` suffix, it doesn't seem to be helpful. The copy-n-paste code in main() is not so bad, maybe keep it, as certainly it is very clear. But there's an opportunity to iterate over a list of classes, calling `.create_router()` on each one.